# Refresh a job in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two inputs in livewire view. When a value is entered in the first input, a calculation is performed in the component based on the data received from the api and the value in the first input, the result of which is displayed in the second input. Now I want that calculation to be done again every ten seconds and displayed in the second input. According to the livewire documentation, I used the `poll`, but only the view was refreshed and the new value was not displayed.I will put the codes below.

inputs :

```
<input wire:model="unit" type="text" class="form-control form-control-xl" style="text-align: center" value="0">
</br>
<input id="toman" type="text" style="text-align: center" class="form-control form-control-xl">
```

component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Order;

use App\Models\Currency;
use App\Models\Network;
use Livewire\Component;

class Buy extends Component
{
    public $currencySelect ='btc';
    public $unit;


    public function mount()
    {
        $this->unit = 0;
    }

    public function updatedUnit()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'unit' => 'numeric',
        ]);
            if ($this->unit !== ''){
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('changeToman', [
                    'toman' => calculatPrice($this->currencySelect , $this->unit),
                ]);
            }
    }

    
    public function render()
    {
        $currencies = Currency::where('buy_status', 'active')->get();
        return view('livewire.frontend.order.buy')->with('currencies', $currencies);
    }
}
```

and this for set value in second input:

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener('changeToman', event => {
  $('#toman').val(new Intl.NumberFormat('ir-IR', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3}).format(event.detail.toman));
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that calculatPrice is a public method of the component. Don't understand well how every 10 seconds will perform this function if any change in first input is done.

```
public $calculated, $unit;

public function reCalculate()
{
   if($this->unit) {      // if input unit has value call the method and assign value
      $this->calculated = $this->calculatPrice($this->currencySelect , $this->unit);
   }  
}

//......

<div wire:poll.10000ms="reCalculate">  // every 10 sec call the method 
   <input wire:model="unit" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align: center">
{{ $calculated }}
</div>
```

Comment: CalculatePrice is a helper